# Limit maximum steps in igraph using all_simple_paths (R/CRAN)

Tags: r, dataframe, igraph, cran

I have been using igraphs all_simple_paths command to take an input, such as df:

```
 To        From
 A         B         
 B         C         
 C         D         
 A         F         
 F         E         
 E         D
```

and turn it into an output, such as df2:

```
                    Protein1  Protein2  Protein3 Protein4 
        Pathway1    A          B        C        D 
        Pathway2    A          E        F        D
```

This works for smaller dataframe, but the actual dataframe I need to analyze is 4,000 lines long in Excel.  Whenever I try to run the code seen at the bottom of this question, my computer either crashes or it takes a very, very long time.

I think this is because all_simple_paths finds ALL of the paths from one point to another (some of which are upwards of 20 steps long).  All I need for my analysis is 4 steps.  igraph's all_shortest_paths function, for my data, only includes three steps.

So, does anyone know how to limit the possible amount of steps in all_simple_paths?  The only answer I have been able to find is from github (https://github.com/igraph/igraph/issues/774), but I do not know how to "create neighborhoods explicitly".

The code I used for this is (which requires xlsx and igraph) is:

-I download the file that holds the "links"

```
links<-read.csv("/users/Desktop/Sortilin.csv", header=TRUE, as.is=T)
Links<-as.data.frame(links)
```

-I make a dataframe of the nodes from the "links" file

```
nodes<-as.character(unique(unlist(Links)))
Nodes<-as.data.frame(nodes)
```

-I make an igraph object showing the steps from Sortilin to PIMT.

```
net<- graph_from_data_frame(d=Links, vertices=Nodes, directed=T)
```

-This is the step that crashes my computer!

```
PathsE<-all_shortest_paths(net, from="Sortilin", to="PIMT")
```

-and then I manipulate the output into a dataframe, etc.

I'm pretty new to R (and coding in general!) so any help would be appreciated!!